# Setting a pixel on a canavs imageData for a given X and Y

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently setting individual pixels on the canvas within a loop using the fillRect method like so:

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba("+colourR+","+colourG+","+colourB+",255)";
context.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 )
```

This method works fine, however it, and putImageData, is very slow. So I've decided to try and set the pixels individually within the loop, then use a single call to putImageData when ready to output to the screen, like so:

```
var screenImageData = context.getImageData(0,0,800,600);
var pixelBuffer = screenImageData.data;    
pixelBuffer[(x*4) + (y*(screenImageData.width * 4))] = colourR;
pixelBuffer[(x*4) + (y*(screenImageData.width * 4)) + 1] = colourG;
pixelBuffer[(x*4) + (y*(screenImageData.width * 4)) + 2] = colourB;
pixelBuffer[(x*4) + (y*(screenImageData.width * 4)) + 3] = 255;

...

context.putImageData(screenImageData,0,0);
```

However, this generates a completely different output to the fillRect method (it just looks like jumbled up garbage). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why is it necessary for you to use getImageData() and putImageData() in this case?

Comment: could you put the testcase somewhere?

Comment: why are you doing `screenImageData.width * 4`?

Comment: Because the pixels are stored in the array in R,G,B,A format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was in the way x and y were calculated, apparently the putImageData converts them to ints automatically. Using Math.floor on them was all that was required.